# Unable to update users timezone correctly

Tags: time, issue, zone

User has requested to update timezones. 
e.g - (GMT-08:00) Pacific Standard Time (America/Los_Angeles) for a user.
I update TimesZoneIdKey of this user as - America/Los_Angeles.

Expected - (GMT-08:00) Pacific Standard Time (America/Los_Angeles
Actual -    (GMT-08:00) Pacific Daylight Time (America/Los_Angeles

Facing same issue for each timezone. Even (GMT-08:00) Pacific Standard Time (America/Los_Angeles is not available in timezone picklist. Please suggest me where i am doing wrong.

Comment: so when you edit the user via the UI and change the timezone then click save, it does not save the changes?

Comment: When i edit user detail - GMT-08:00) Pacific Standard Time (America/Los_Angeles  this value is not avaialable in timezone list.

Comment: Can find only (GMT-08:00) Pacific Daylight Time (America/Los_Angeles)

Comment: Thats all that is supported: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_supported_timezone.htm&type=0

Comment: I think , TimeZones have unique key ids. America/Los_Angeles. is the key for Pacific Standard Time (America/Los_Angeles and Pacific daylight Time (America/Los_Angeles). And it gets updated autometically based on the standard time or daylight time.